# mysqldump trigger crashed tables

Tags: mysql

We had a database crash this morning starting at 1 minute past midnight (when the database backup runs). The exception emails I was getting said

```
 "Table './core/content' is marked as crashed and should be repaired".
```

My question is basically, can mysqldump cause tables to crash, if so how and why? And are there any tools which can detect a crashed table and run a repair on it?

Thanks in advance.